# Type error while building deployments on Vercel

Tags: typescript, next.js, vercel

I am deploying my build on Vercel. It is working fine locally but when I try to build it on vercel I am getting this error:

```
    [![Type error: Type '(ref: HTMLDivElement | null) => HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefined'.
  Type '(ref: HTMLDivElement | null) => HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
    Type 'HTMLDivElement | null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
  48 |     <>
  49 |       <div
> 50 |         ref={(ref) => (node.current = ref)}
     |         ^
  51 |         css={(theme) => ({
  52 |           width: !isTabletOrMobile ? "auto" : "100vw",
  53 |           height: "98%",
error Command failed with exit code 1][1]][1]
```

Comment: Can you try `ref={(ref as LegacyRef<HTMLDivElement> | undefine) => (node.current = ref)}`? Just a guess.

Comment: Ok, let me try and get back to you.

Comment: What is the purpose of setting `node.current` in the arrow function? It supposed to be like `<div ref={ref}>` in your div.

Comment: I tried with ref={ref} as well, still got the same error. @BaljkaGan

Comment: It is not working with your code. @LajosArpad

Comment: I think it is better to understand your situation with your actual code lines instead compiles one.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
const containerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
```

```
<div ref={containerRef}>
...
</div>
```

After this wherever you want to access the ref you have to access it like this : `chartContainerRef.current`